# Covering a Polygon with Minimum number of circles with fixed locations

Tags: qgis, optimization

In QGIS, I have a vector polygon of a fixed size and shape. I also have a set of circles of a fixed radius and fixed location, which cover part of the polygon. What I would like to do is remove as many of the circles as possible while leaving as few gaps as possible, a gap being an area not covered by the circles. No circle should have overlap with another circle of more than 90% (or 80% or 70%- I am trying to run a few scenarios) of its area. I would also like to treat circles which go off the edge of the polygon in the same way as overlap, i.e. a circle with more than 90% of its area not covering the polygon would be eliminated. Inevitably there will be times when two or more circles could be chosen, I would like to prioritize them based on specific attributes. Here is a picture of the complete set of circles(pink) and the polygon I need them to cover (blue).

[image]

I am new to GIS and any extra elaboration on how to implement is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to begin with a more objective, quantitative statement of your problem: what is your definition of a "gap"? How will you measure how "few" of them there are? Precisely how would the "prioritization" interact with the objective of minimizing gaps?

Comment: Furthermore pictures say more than words, so if you can add a screenshot displaying your problem that would ease up everything for people trying to help you. If you're not allowed to post an image, simply include the link to an imagehoster

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4828/algorithm-to-place-maximum-number-of-points-within-constrained-area-at-a-minimum

Comment: I dont see anything but semantic similarity. This is subtractive, and the circles location is fixed not variable like in your example. Im not packing.